# How do I open a webbrower on Android from kivy

Tags: android, kivy, python-webbrowser

I am trying to open a webbrowser on Android from a kivy app.

The solution below works as I would expect on Unix, but when built and deployed on Android, nothing happens. I have used the default buildozer spec file [EDIT] and uncommented:

```
android.permissions = INTERNET
```

[/EDIT].

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
import webbrowser

root = Builder.load_string('''
<MainFrame>:
    Button:
        text: 'Click here'
        on_release: root.on_button_click()
''')

class MainFrame(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_button_click(self):
        webbrowser.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')

class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainFrame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BasicApp().run()
```

Comment: This is what I use for Android too and it works OK. Perhaps your problem is something else...

Comment: @embryo Thanks. Any idea what?

Comment: Can you upload somewhere the compiled apk to check it?

Comment: @Psionman: Could please share your *buildozer.spec*.

Comment: @ikolim the spec is at https://justpaste.it/4lxq0

Comment: @Psionman: What is the buildozer version that you are using? If you are using v0.39, you have to specify the Python version in requirements e.g. `requirements=python3,kivy`

Comment: @ikolim I've upgraded buildozer to version 0.39. Now it just hangs on "Installing/updating SDK platform tools if necessary". Left for 4 days, but it was still hanging there.

Comment: @Psionman: If it hangs while executing `buildozer android debug`, it is waiting for the user to accept the license agreement from Google. Type *Y* and press ENTER key.

Comment: @ikolim I've run into further problems with the load. I've started a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468917/how-to-fix-buildozer-build-fails-with-cmake-error